# Using ion-list to display the sub-items of the selected item

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm creating an app where there is a list of items displayed. when an item is selected it will be re-directed to another page where another set of items are listed with check box, so that the items can be check-boxed for further process. Im able to select the item from the list of first page but the problem is in the next page it doesn't display items related to the selected item and it remain blank.Please help me to resolve it.

html page1:

```
<ion-list>
     <ion-item ng-model="carBrand" ng-repeat="name in carSelect"  ng-click="selectItem(carBrand)">
     <!--ion-item ng-click="selectItem(value)" ng-repeat="value in carSelect" ng-model="value.selected"-->
         {{name.name}}
     </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

html page2:

```
<ion-checkbox ng-repeat="brandType in newCarList">
     <div align="center"><span>{{brandType.types}}</span></div>
</ion-checkbox><br><br>
```

controller:

```
carService.factory('carRepository',function(){
   var brandList={};
   brandList.data= [
       {'name':'Benz', 'types':['Truck', 'Regular']},
       {'name':'BMW', 'types':['Oversize', 'Motorcycle']},
       {'name':'Bently','types':['Regular']},
       {'name':'Honda','types':['SUV','Truck']},
       {'name':'Lexus','types':['Oversize','Motorcycle','Truck']},
       {'name':'Toyota','types':['SUV']}
   ];

  {
    return brandList;
  }
});

carService.controller('carBrand',['$scope','carRepository','$rootScope','$state',function($scope,carRepository,$rootScope,$state){

   $rootScope.carSelect= carRepository.data;
   $scope.newCarList=[];
   $scope.selectedItem = 'select';
   $scope.selectItem = function (key) {
      $scope.newCarList.push(key);
      $state.go('app.CarDetails');
   }
   $scope.addEntry = function () {
      $state.go('app.carEdit');
   };
}])
```

Answer (score 1):

This would correctly:

Within your config of your application, should I set the state that v to receive the parameter as follows:

```
carService.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    .state('html2', {
        templateUrl: 'overview',
        params:      ['value'],
        controller:  'HtmlCtrl2'
    })
    ......
})
```

Here you say that you will receive a parameter called value.

From Html1Ctrl
In the first controller, that is, in html 1 according to your example, you define this:

```
.controller('HomeCtrl1', function($state){
    $scope.redirect = function(){
        params = { 'value': 1 };
        $state.go('view', params);
    }
})
```

Here you say that when that function is called "redirect" arme value and send as parameter to reroute

In HtmlCtrl2 And in the controller 2 you get ...

```
.controller('HtmlCtrl2', function($scope, $stateParams) {
    var value= $stateParams[0];
});
```

Comment: can you attach working plnkr so it will be for the first time user like me.

Comment: At the moment I can not realize it, but to understand better editare my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you navigate to the next page that page should know what was selected in the previous page. Because you are using `$state.go` try using `$stateparams` which you pass to the next page. Something like:

**Current page**

```
$state.go('app.CarDetails',{value: value})
```

**Next Page -> app.CarDetails**

```
$scope.selected = $stateparams.value;
```

On the next page you can use the value to lookup and pre-populate information required from the previous page click.

Remember to inject/add `$stateparams` in the controller definition.

Comment: It is not working. Is there anyother way to resolve it.